# Maximum number of open connections reached (in webBrowser object)

Tags: c#, proxy, windows-10, webbrowser-control, firewall

My problem is I'm developing an application instantiates multiple webbrowser objects, each of them browsing the internet with a different proxy. What appears in the web browser window when browsing is the title of my query: "Maximum number of open connections reached". Reading documentation seems to be a restriction of my own Windows firewall.

How can I configure it to allow me to increase the number of connections with C #?

The proxy of each webBrowser I configure it like this:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal extern static bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);

        internal struct Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
        {
            internal int dwAccessType;
            internal IntPtr proxy;
            internal IntPtr proxyBypass;
        }

        internal const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
        internal const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;

        struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
        struct_IPI.proxy = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(myProxy.Address.Host + ":" + myProxy.Address.Port);
        struct_IPI.proxyBypass = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");

        this.intptrStruct = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI));

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, true);

        InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
```

Thank you very much.